# Single key pair to private instances + Multiple key pair bastion host

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

Scenario:

1. N developers, each on with their key/pairs
2. One bastion host that store on authorized_keys the public keys OS all developers
3. Single key-pair (A) that holds access to all private instance

From the articles that I read the private-key (A) are shared among the developers. Is it a common approach?

But I wouldn't like to distribute the key-pair (A) to all my developers, so I could rotate it. This private key will be stored encrypted just in the bastion host.

Answer (score 0):

For SSH to work,

The private key needs to be on developer machine, the instance needs to have the public key corresponding to the private key.

Ideal scenario is to have a account created for each user and add the public of the user to .ssh folder under that user account.

But if there are too many users, you can create one account and add multiple public keys to the .ssh file. You can always revoke the user by removing the public key.

In either of the cases, the private and public key combination should be unique and the private key should not be shared.

Comment: Each developer has its own private key, but they the need to have the private key from my private instances (behind the bastion)

Comment: not necessarily, if the same account(s) & public keys are setup on the private instances, you can ask developers to use ssh forwarding for logging into the private instances.

Comment: Sure! Is it a common approach? I was thinking use one key pair per user and one single key pair for my private instances. If I want to revoke an user I just need to delete the public key on bastion. What do u think?

Comment: If you don't use the ssh forwarding, you will have to put the private key of the instance on the bastion. That's never recommended.

Comment: I understand! I will use the SSH forwarding but just think instead of user one key pair for each developer and set bastion and private instances with public key, I will use one key pair for each dev and a single key pair for private instances. I will share among dev this key pair to enable SSH forwarding

Comment: the one key you will have on the bastion, what kind of access will be available to user on which it will be setup inside the private instance.

Comment: I will not have a key in the bastion. The developer will have two keys: one for connect to bastion and other to connect to private instances

Comment: since you are sharing the instance private key, kind of access is critical. If its just a read only kind of access it may be ok